# Spring MVC 4 can't find page

Tags: java, jsp, spring-mvc

I need your help.

I'm new on Spring MVC(Actually whole of Spring.)

I follwed an example of Spring MVC 4(Anotation base). I did every step as carefully but I couldn't.

Here is my AppConfig.java class

```
package main.java.config;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.ComponentScan;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver;

/**
  * Created by tugrul on 24.04.2017.
*/
@Configuration
@ComponentScan(basePackages = "main.java.*")
public class AppConfig {

@Bean(name="viewResolver")
public InternalResourceViewResolver getViewResolver(){

    InternalResourceViewResolver viewResolver = new          InternalResourceViewResolver();
    viewResolver.setPrefix("/WEB-INF/pages/");
    viewResolver.setSuffix(".jsp");
    return viewResolver;
}
}
```

Here is my AppInitializer.java class :

```
package main.java.config;

import org.springframework.web.WebApplicationInitializer;
import             org.springframework.web.context.support.AnnotationConfigWebApplicationContext;
import org.springframework.web.filter.CharacterEncodingFilter;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet;

import javax.servlet.FilterRegistration;
import javax.servlet.ServletContext;
import javax.servlet.ServletException;
import javax.servlet.ServletRegistration;

/**
   * Created by tugrul on 24.04.2017.
 */
  public class AppInitializer implements WebApplicationInitializer{
  public void onStartup(ServletContext servletContext) throws   ServletException {
    AnnotationConfigWebApplicationContext appContext = new AnnotationConfigWebApplicationContext();
    appContext.register(AppConfig.class);

    ServletRegistration.Dynamic dispatcher = servletContext.addServlet("SpringDispatcher",
            new DispatcherServlet(appContext));
    dispatcher.setLoadOnStartup(1);
    dispatcher.addMapping("/");

    dispatcher.setInitParameter("contextClass",appContext.getClass().getName());

    FilterRegistration.Dynamic fr = servletContext.addFilter("encodingFilter", CharacterEncodingFilter.class);
    fr.setInitParameter("encoding", "UTF-8");
    fr.setInitParameter("forceEncoding", "true");
    fr.addMappingForUrlPatterns(null, true, "/*");


}
}
```

Here is My DenemeController.java class :

```
package main.java.controller;

import org.springframework.stereotype.Controller;
import org.springframework.ui.Model;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;

/**
   * Created by tuğrul on 24.04.2017.
*/

@Controller
public class DenemeController {

@RequestMapping("/welcome")
public String sayHello(Model model) {
    model.addAttribute("greeting", "Welcome back to Java Tuğrul." +
            "\nYou're right way." +
            "\nAll your time on software engineering you have to keep learn new things");

    return "welcome back";
}
}
```

And I have a hello.jsp file under the WEB-INF/pages/ directory.

The project base url is localhost:8080/deneme. WhenI enter this url to browser I can see index.jsp but When I enter to mapped url is localhost:8080/deneme/welcome I got 404 not found.

Where did I wrong? Could you help me?

Comment: what url are you using to access it?

Comment: do you see clean log when you start your application? Please paste log here is possible

Comment: use urlpattern just "/"

Comment: you should not return "welcome back" but return "hello" instead since that's the name of the view you are trying to resolve

Comment: the project url is http://localhost:8080/deneme when I enter this url browser I can see index.jsp but I want to see http://localhost:8080/deneme/welcome when I this enter 404 not found.

Comment: @rptmat57 thank you. I got it ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your `sayHello` method in DenemeController, you are returning "wellcome back". Instead you should return "hello", which is the name of HTML view file "hello.jsp".

```
@Controller
public class DenemeController {

    @RequestMapping("/welcome")
    public String sayHello(Model model) {
        model.addAttribute("greeting", "Welcome back to Java Tuğrul." +
            "\nYou're right way." +
            "\nAll your time on software engineering you have to keep learn new things");

        return "hello";
    }
}
```

Comment: @luffy you are wellcome